# Typo3 download remote files and create a file object

Tags: file, download, typo3

How do I save a remote file to local storage in Typo3 v10.

Having the following code, no files are getting saved in fileadmin storage

```
private function saveFileFromUri($fileUrl)
    {
        $urlParts = parse_url($fileUrl);
        $pathParts = pathinfo($urlParts['path']);
        $fileName = $pathParts['basename'];

        $file = GeneralUtility::getUrl($fileUrl);
        $temporaryFile = GeneralUtility::tempnam('temp/' . $fileName);
        $storage = $this->defaultStorage->createFolder($pathParts['dirname']);

        if ($file === false) {
            $error = sprintf(
                'File %s could not be fetched.',
                $fileUrl
            );
            if (isset($report['message'])) {
                $error .= ' ' . sprintf(
                    'Reason: %s (code: %s)',
                    $report['message'],
                    $report['error'] ?? 0
                );
            }
            throw new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\ResourceDoesNotExistException(
                $error,
                1613555057
            );
        }
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($file);

        GeneralUtility::writeFileToTypo3tempDir(
            $temporaryFile,
            $file
        );

        $fileObject = $storage->addFile(
            $temporaryFile,
            $storage,
            $fileName
        );

        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($fileObject);
    }
```

What is the right way to save remote files in typo3 and create a fileObject?

Comment: Security side note: If the `$fileUrl` variable is under user control, please ensure to verify the `$fileName` variable against the TYPO3 `fileDenyPattern` (see `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Security\FileNameValidator`) in order to avoid that files get downloaded which the webserver might execute (e.g. PHP scripts). It is also highly recommended to restrict the file download to a limited sets of accepted mime types (see `TYPO3\CMS\Form\Mvc\Validation\MimeTypeValidator`).

Comment: thanks @derhansen for Feedback. The parsed files are getting validated previously but is nice to get know about the core API validation classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPO3 has an API to get or add files via the File Abstraction Layer (FAL).

This example adds a new file in the root folder of the default storage:

```php
$storageRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\StorageRepository::class);
$storage = $storageRepository->getDefaultStorage();
$newFile = $storage->addFile(
      '/tmp/temporary_file_name.ext',
      $storage->getRootLevelFolder(),
      'final_file_name.ext'
);
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#adding-a-file) for details.

Comment: Thanks I found between. Now I'm looking for the API which would define the custom storage where the uploads should be saved